How to identify the object when the element index value is dynamic in dom, using tosca how to identify the object
if there is an element which consists of input tag where the index value keep on changing how to identify the object using Tosca. Any suggestion in identifying the object will be helpful. Thinking of using the JavaScript executor but did not find any possible source to implement it.
I have tried using the xpath, where I'm buffering the index value but eventually i have to keep updating the value in my test for the new build. Tried with anchor but there are multiple options with same name, it worked for some time later it started giving the issue where it says having multiple options with same name.
